# Certificate error when running docker container provided in UA Cloud Library

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, opc-ua

I am using the following GitHub repository: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-CloudLibrary
In the documentation, it is explained how to run the docker container. Nevertheless, I am encountering an error I cannot deal with when running it locally in wsl2 using Visual Studio. Do you have any suggestion how to solve the issue?

```
~/sandbox/Subscription_Service/UA-CloudLibrary$ docker compose up
WARN[0000] The "APPDATA" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "APPDATA" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
[+] Running 3/0
 ✔ Container ua-cloudlibrary-pgadmin-1          Created                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 ✔ Container ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  Created                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 ✔ Container ua-cloudlibrary-db-1               Created                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
Attaching to ua-cloudlibrary-db-1, ua-cloudlibrary-pgadmin-1, ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1
ua-cloudlibrary-db-1               |
ua-cloudlibrary-db-1               | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
ua-cloudlibrary-db-1               |
ua-cloudlibrary-pgadmin-1          | postfix/postlog: starting the Postfix mail system
ua-cloudlibrary-db-1               | 2023-12-10 07:20:04.991 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
ua-cloudlibrary-db-1               | 2023-12-10 07:20:04.997 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
ua-cloudlibrary-db-1               | 2023-12-10 07:20:04.998 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
ua-cloudlibrary-db-1               | 2023-12-10 07:20:05.010 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
ua-cloudlibrary-db-1               | 2023-12-10 07:20:05.038 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-12-10 07:10:25 UTC
ua-cloudlibrary-db-1               | 2023-12-10 07:20:05.084 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |       Storing keys in a directory '/app' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  | Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  | To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  | For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1  |    at Opc.Ua.Cloud.Library.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/UACloudLibraryServer/Program.cs:line 39
ua-cloudlibrary-ua-cloudlibrary-1 exited with code 139
ua-cloudlibrary-pgadmin-1          | [2023-12-10 07:20:25 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
ua-cloudlibrary-pgadmin-1          | [2023-12-10 07:20:25 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
ua-cloudlibrary-pgadmin-1          | [2023-12-10 07:20:25 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
ua-cloudlibrary-pgadmin-1          | [2023-12-10 07:20:25 +0000] [83] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 83
```

I have run the command suggested in the error message with the following result:

```
~/sandbox/Subscription_Service/UA-CloudLibrary$ dotnet dev-certs https

A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.
```

Comment: What error are you getting, HTTPS based? Try putting HTTPS on Volumes, [see this](https://www.yogihosting.com/docker-https-aspnet-core/).